# Is it possible generated from local file image from html5-canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, todataurl

My canvas has image which programly generated from local file or from images from internet. When I try to save it using toDataURl function I get secure error. How can I save result (without server, using only js ) and is it possible?

I know about [security rule](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules) but maybe there is some solution to bypass this rule

All my code is in [github](https://github.com/aknew/imageCompare) if need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame!  Don't bypass rules built to provide security for our users.

*The key to satisfying CORS security and still getting what you need is to let the user select the image file you need to load into canvas.*

If the user selects the file, CORS security is satisfied and you can use the canvas as you need (including using canvas.toDataURL to save the canvas).

Here are the steps to let a user select a file from their local drive:

1. Add an html input element with type="file"
2. The user clicks browse on this element and selects their file
3. When the user clicks OK, use window.URL.createObjectURL to create a URL from their selected file.
4. Create a new Image and set its source to the URL you created in #3.
5. Use context.drawImage to draw your new image on the canvas.
6. The resulting canvas is CORS compliant so canvas.toDataURL will work.

Here's example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    $("#fileInput").change(function(e){
        var URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
                canvas.width=img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                ctx.fillStyle="black";
                ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.height-30,canvas.width,30);
                ctx.fillStyle="white";
                ctx.font="18px verdana";
                ctx.fillText("I'm OK with CORS!",5,canvas.height-8);
        }
        img.src = url;
    });

    $("#save").click(function(){
        var html="<p>Right-click on image below and Save-Picture-As</p>";
        html+="<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"' alt='from canvas'/>";
        var tab=window.open();
        tab.document.write(html);        
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">    
    <button id="save">Save</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why shame? I'm not web-developer and see js second time in my life :) Thanks for your answer, but what's about using picture from third part site, is it possible?

Comment: Just joking about shame :)  Sure, in the example code when you hit the "browse" button you can even paste in an http:// URL and load that image from a 3rd party site. (3rd party loading takes a while...be patient).

Comment: Here's a use case foiled by this SecurityError: a bookmarklet for taking `<video>` element screenshots works when the video is served via `http(s)` but not when opened locally, with a `file:///` protocol. The picture doesn't have a src URL as it was just generated by `.drawImage()`. If `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()` is not allowed on `file:///` resources then this useful utility is broken for local videos, but not online videos. `.toBlob()` is subject to the same restrictions. :/